# Using php conditional operator to set values in mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-operator

I have the following code. The add stats query echo statement returns a blank, not sure what is wrong with the query. Is it the conditional operator? category_tally is a multi-dimensional array so i need to check if the key exists, before assigning the value.

```
$add_stats_query=   "INSERT INTO stats(word_count,
                            sentence_count,
                            avg_sent_length,
                            7charword_count,
                            liwc_1_per,
                            liwc_2_per) VALUES (
                            ".$word_count.",
                            ".$sentence_count.",
                            ".$avg_sentence_length.",
                            ".$sevenchar_words.",
                            ".(array_key_exists(1,$category_tally)?$category_tally[1]["count"]:0).",
                            ".(array_key_exists(2,$category_tally)?$category_tally[2]["count"]:0).");";

echo    "*********".$add_stats_query."<br><br>";
```

Comment: I pasted this exact code and tested it: it works perfectly fine. What I think is happening is that you have an error in your code (somewhere OTHER than in the part you posted) and you have display_errors turned Off. Turn it on, and debug your code.

Comment: Thanks, there was an error in a previous statement. display_errors pointed it out..